# Structuring value initialization

Tags: f#

I am beginning with F# and I can't understand what is the best way to structure value initialization:

```
let x = TryCalculateX() // for example, searching in DB
if x = null then
    // for example, we create it ourself and out it into DB
    let x = TryAnotherCalcultaion() 
    someProcessing x // x is now initialized => Ok
someProcessing x // here I use old, not initialized x! => Fails
```

How do you handle similar situations?

Upd. The best I devised was:

```
let getX() =
    let res = TryCalculateX() 
    if res = null then
        let res = TryAnotherCalcultaion() 
        res
    else
        res
```

That's not really cool, IMHO

Upd 2. @ChaosPandion suggested good fix:

```
let x = 
    match TryCalculateX() with
    | null -> TryAnotherCalculation() 
    | x -> x
someProcessing x
```

But this becomes also not very great if one additional level of nesting is added:

```
let x = 
    match TryCalculateX() with
    | null -> 
        match TryAnotherCalculation()  with
        | null -> OneMoreCalculation()
        | y -> y
    | x -> x
someProcessing x
```

Maybe there is some more general pattern to apply?

Upd 3. Thanks to @ChaosPandion again here's a general solution:

```
// Different initialization strategies
let x() = printfn("x"); None
let y() = printfn("y"); None
let z() = printfn("z"); Some(1)

// Sequence of strategies
let a = seq { 
    yield x()
    yield y()
    yield z()
}

// Initializing function
let init what = Seq.find (fun el -> Option.isSome el) what

// Initializing
let b = init a
```

F# interactive prints:

> x    y    z     ...    val b : int option = Some 1

Comment: Nested chains like this are often called the "pyramid of doom" and crop up in many situations, such as async "futures". 
Computation expressions or bind can simplify the code tremendously
See http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-continuations/ and http://alfredodinapoli.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/humbly-simple-f-maybe-monad-application-scenario/ for examples.

Comment: Yes, I know about computational expressions but never used them as I am relatively new to F#. Maybe you could provide an example how to use them in this case? I guess it might be useful for many programmers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is a nice convention to follow. It can work with `null` but I would recomend returning an `'a option` type.

**Option**

```
let x = 
    match TryCalculateX() with
    | Some x -> x
    | None -> TryAnotherCalculation() 
someProcessing x
```

**Null**

```
let x = 
    match TryCalculateX() with
    | null -> TryAnotherCalculation() 
    | x -> x
someProcessing x
```

**Sequence**

Assuming you write each attempt to return an `option` then you can write an elegant sequence of attempts.

```
let x = seq {
            yield firstTry ()
            yield secondTry ()
            yield thirdTry ()
            yield sensibleDefault
        } |> Seq.pick id
someProcessing x
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Your code definitely looks cleaner than my original version. At the same time even it will become messy if there are more conditions to check, f.e. if there is three cases instead of two. What do you think, how would you simplify mode complex case?

Comment: @Rustam - The ability of F# to perform complex pattern matching should cover a whole lot of cases. That being said, you can extend it using a `when` guard. With theses 2 tools you should be able to write expressive and concise code. I would read through the docs to truly understand the [match expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx).

Comment: @Rustam - I almost forgot to mention [active patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) which allow you to extend it even further should you see the need.

Comment: As far as I understand `when` guard wouldn't be helpful in case of several nested checks, f.e. if `TryAnotherCalculation` returned `None`, we would use some `OneMoreCalculation`. With this, pattern matching would become nested, which is also not very exciting. The same seems to be true for active patterns. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Rustam - You are not wrong. To combat such indentation you would probably want to write a lazy sequence that you iterate until you find a value that was not `None`.

Comment: Now that's a funny idea, and seems to fit perfectly!